# wc -l Sometimes Outputs Wrong Number

Tags: bash, shell, wc

I have some code like this:

```
while true
do
    who | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | grep -v "erik" > "/home/erik/logintester/users.txt"

    lines=$(< "/home/erik/logintester/users.txt" wc -l)

    echo "$lines"

done
```

It's supposed to echo a "1" whenever there is another person logged in, but instead I get 1's and 0's mixed in. Is there a fix to this problem? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Provide a copy of `users.txt` from the case where `wc -l` is wrong. Though you should *really* be using `mktemp` to ensure that each copy of this script has its own, unique copy of the temporary file, if you're going to use one.

Comment: If you want unique users you should use `sort -u`. Also `grep -v "erik"` is a bad regex because it will filter out other users that include "erik", like "erika", "erikssen", etc. you may want to grep with something like "^erik$".

Comment: @vdavid Thanks for the suggestion! I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming BOC's suggestion of a second process interfering is correct, you are contributing to the problem by using an unnecessary file (which provides a shared resource that allows the race condition to occur).

All you need is a single pipeline. (Capturing the output of the pipeline in order to call `echo` is also unnecessary.)

```
while true; do
    who | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | grep -v "erik" | wc -l
done
```

You can simply it further by using a single call to `awk` (the `sort` doesn't seem to serv any purpose; the count is the same no matter what order the output is in):

```
while true; do
    who | awk '$1 != "erik" {count+=1} END {print count}'
done
```

Comment: `sort` allows to get unique users. I guess Erik forgot to pipe it to `uniq` or to call `sort -u`. Also `awk`is overkill, `grep -c -v erik` gives the same result and is probably more efficient.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you have a second instance of your code that is running at the same time. Check the running processes and kill the previous one.

The command

```
who | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | grep -v "erik" > "/home/erik/logintester/users.txt"
```

is not atomic. It first create an empty file users.txt, then create all the processes for each commands of the pipe, then these processes write into the file. This gives a lapse of time where the file is empty. When you have two processes running the same code, there is a probability that one process displays the content of the empty file created by the other process.

Avoiding temporary file like suggested by @chepner is always a good idea.

Comment: It worked! Why does this happen? Will you be so kind as to edit your question why? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I would really like to accept both of your answers!